# Update in MicrosoftAjax.js is not reflect in my local Visual Studio 2005

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-2.0, internet-explorer-10, microsoft-ajax

I got java script error:

> SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value must be an integer.
>   Parameter name: y Actual value was 326.739990234375.

When I testing application in  IE 10 browser. I did googling and found [this solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936993) from Microsoft Support.
I have modified `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftAjax.debug.js` files as per above article.

But After modified the javascriptfiles, when I run the application using Visual Studio 2005, I did not get the updated `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftAjax.debug.js` files.

So my question is: How can I get the updated versions of these two javascripts files.

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hacking JS files try upgrading your project to a newer .NET framework:

http://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/05/01/solution-for-ie10-error-script5022-sys-argumentoutofrangeexception-value-must-be-an-integer/